# Best practice database design for composite schedules

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, validation, database-design, mapping

I am working on a database which handles different schedules, in my case composed with half-days.

My concept with table `TBL_HalfDay`, `TBL_Day`:

- `TBL_HalfDay` consists of a char `daytime` ('M' or 'A', morning/afternoon), a date and a foreign key referring to an employee who is in charge, as well as other data
- `TBL_Day` consists of a date, a foreign key `fk_morning` and a foreign key `fk_afternoon`, both referring to `TBL_HalfDay`
- The entities of `TBL_Day` will be mapped in an external Java-Application, using Hibernate. My goal there is to choose a range of dates (`startDate/endDate`), which creates a List with all `TBL_Day` entities who fall into that range

---

My question is about best practice in my design concept.

- What is usually the best approach for databases handling days/schedules who are composed of multiple parts?
- Where do I need a mapping? I inserted the date column in both, `TBL_Day` and `TBL_HalfDay`, which is efficient for a java mapper, but might cause redundant data?
- Two foreign keys referring to same table: yay or nay?
- I use 1:1 relationships between both tables, is that a good idea?
- And last but not least, should the two tables really be associated with each other or should the java mapper take care of that?

Please do not only post about my concept, but also about the general mindset when designing databases working with schedules, so it can also be helpful to others.

Comment: For the `HalfDay` table, are there only two records for any particular date? If so, what is the point of `Day` table, given that a date value itself binds to related `HalfDay` records together?

Comment: Yes, only two `HalfDay` records per date. My idea was to split them up because every `HalfDay` has some information on its own, for example different responsibilities divided by employees ect.

Comment: But do you have other information on the `Day` table? If not, you do not need that table at all.

Comment: Good point, thanks! what about the rest of my concept?